# Hazelcast bean serialisation in python

Tags: java, python, hazelcast, serializable

I was trying to use two hazelcast client one in Java and one in python.

My bean class is following,

```
class  Sample implements Serializable { 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = someId;

        private String val;

        public String getVal() {
            return val;
        }    
        public void setVal(String val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

}
```

Python bean,

```
class Sample(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.val = ''
   def getVal(self):
      return self.val
   def setVal(self,val):
      self.val =val
```

Java code to add an entry,

```
ClientConfig config = getClientConfig(IP, PORT);
HazelcastInstance hazelCastInstance = HazelcastClient
                .newHazelcastClient(config);
IMap<String,Sample> map = hazelCastInstance.getMap("sample"); 
Sample s =new Sample();
s.setVal("test");
map.put("test", s);
hazelCastInstance.shutdown();
```

Python code to read the bean,

```
my_async_map = client.get_map('sample')
future = my_async_map.values()
r = future.result()
print r
```

I am getting an exception `hazelcast.exception.HazelcastSerializationError: Missing Serializer for type-id:-100`. When I use `IdentifiedDataSerializable`. It works fine.

How can I deserialise a bean which is Serialised by java ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use `java.lang.Serializable` since this serialization format is specific to Java (or more specifically to a special JVM implementation and Java version). Therefore you should always either use `(Identified)DataSerializable` (which is not an extension of `java.lang.Serializable`), `Portable` or any multi-language available serialization like Protobuf, Apache Avro, Apache Thrift, ...

Comment: Thank you noctarius